# Get list of most common users who accssed from https_access.log

Tags: apache, https

Is there any easy way to get list of most common users who accessed from https_access.log

Answer (score 0):

If the username appears in the 2nd column in the access log, then you can extract and count it thus:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2 https_access.log | sort | uniq --count
```

This sets the delimiter to a space, and takes the 2nd column (this number might need to change, depending on the log format). Then it puts all the similar items together, and finally de-duplicates them, putting the count in front.

You can add: `| sort -nr` to sort thelines, highest count first (that is the '-r' for reverse, or descending sort)